# What vitimins are there?

Tags: health

What vitimins are there and why and what are they?

they do appear in apples and other fruit but just how many are there

Answer (score 0):

Vitamins are compounds that the body needs to function. They are similar to minerals but differ in the fact that Vitamins are organic and minerals aren't. There are 6 vitamins (A,B,C,D,E,K) but many are suffixed with a number, like B12 or D3. They can be found in fruits and vegetables, as well from meat or other sources. 
In total, there are 13 different amount of vitamins that humans need in some amount to function:
A, B1, B2, B3, B5, B6, B7, B9, B12, C, D, E, K

Comment: thanks jacob. i need this for a project or writing informal language one

Comment: You do not appear to have read the guided tour and I imagine also not [how to write a good answer](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Your answer provides no evidence in its support. This is essential for anyone to judge whether or not it is correct. In fact, the statement "There are 6 vitamins...but many are suffixed with a number" is nonsense. For example Vit B1 (thiamine) and Vit B12 (cobalamin)  are completely different chemically and functionally.